# AWS cloudwatch custom metrics on AWS-Auto Scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have auto-scaling setup currently listed to the CPU usage on scaling in & out. Now there are scenarios that our servers got out of service due to out of memory, I applied custom metrics to get those data on the instance using the Perl scripts. Is it possible to have a scaling policy that listed to those custom metrics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!

Just create an Alarm (eg `Memory-Alarm`) on the Custom Metric and then adjust the Auto Scaling group to scale based on the Memory-Alarm.

You should pick *one metric* to trigger the scaling (CPU *or* Memory) -- attempting to scale with both could cause problems where one alarm is high and another is low.

**Update:**

When creating an Alarm on an Auto Scaling group, it uses only **one alarm** and the alarm uses an **aggregated metric across all instances**. For example, it might be *Average CPU Utilization*. So, if one instance is at 50% and another is at 100%, the metric will be 75%. This way, it won't add instances just because one instance is too busy.

This will probably cause a problem for your memory metric because aggregating memory across the group makes no sense. If one machine has zero memory but another has plenty of memory, it won't add more instances. This is fine because one machine can handle more load, but it won't really be a good measure of 'how busy' the servers are.

If you are experiencing "servers got out of service due to out of memory", the best thing you should do is to configure the Health Check on the load balancer such that it can detect whether an instance can handle requests. If the Auto Scaling health check fails on an instance, then it will stop sending requests to that server until the Health Check is successful. This is the correct way to identify specific instances that are having problems, rather than trying to scale-out.

At any rate, you should investigate your memory issues and determine whether it is actually related to load (how many requests are being handled) or whether it's a memory leak in the application.

Comment: Okay got it. But on how I see it, it will have 1 alarm per instance under the auto-scaling so in my case, 5 instances = 5 alarms. Is it possible to have alarm within the range of tags for flexibility?